# Change Breadcrumbs Home link's URL 2.1

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

[image]

By default clicking breadcrumbs Home will go to home page.
How can I change the URL for home link to be different than store home page?
For Magento 2.1.

Answer (score 5):

You have to override **Breadcrumbs** block under

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php

So, create your module and your **di.xml** in **vendorName/moduleName/etc** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs" type="vendorName\moduleName\Block\Breadcrumbs" />
</config>
```

Then create your Breadcrumbs.php block file in **vendorName/moduleName/Block** folder:

```
<?php

namespace vendorName\moduleName\Block;

class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
{

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if ($breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'home',
                [
                    'label' => __('Home'),
                    'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                    'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                ]
            );

            //$breadcrumbsBlock->setTemplate('WaPoNe_HelloWorld::bread.phtml');

            $title = [];
            $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();

            foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
                $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
            }

            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        }

    }
}
```

In this file you can change parameters in addCrumb() method: *label*, *title* and *link*.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use a plugin for this. Because overriding Magento catalog is not sufficient. You also need to overwrite Magento page, and maybe other extensions.

So the best way is to use the `beforeAddCrumb` plugin method.

You need to create a module and add a di.xml file to configure your plugin :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

  <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs">
    <plugin
      name="VENDOR_MODULE_Plugin_Magento_Theme_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs"
      type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs"
      sortOrder="10"
      disabled="false" />
  </type>    
</config>
```

Then in your plugin file `VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs.php` :

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html;

use \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs as MagentoBreadCrumbs;

class Breadcrumbs
{
    public function beforeAddCrumb(MagentoBreadCrumbs $subject, $crumbName, $crumbInfo)
    {
        if ($crumbName == 'home') {
            $crumbInfo['label'] = __('My new Label');
            $crumbInfo['link'] = 'http://mynewlink.com/';
        }

        return [$crumbName, $crumbInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: On Magento EE 2.2.3 this seemingly only works for category pages, not listing pages.  It worked at one point, but something must have updated recently to stop this from working on listing pages only.

Answer (score 0):

The Home link on product pages is controlled by this file:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/add-home-breadcrumb.js