# Change 'Home' (Label) to "Shop Online" in my breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.4.2, breadcrumbs, porto-theme

I'm trying to make a little change to my breadcrumbs. I'm using Magento 2.4.2

I want to change the "Home" label of my porto theme to "Sports Store".

I'm sure it's a simple change but I'm going crazy.

What is the file that I have to change for it please?

I know how to remove the icon of the house but the problem I have is with the change of the text of the label.

Thanks for the help!

I leave you the code in case it helps you!!

[image]

Comment: Refer to this link for the change label, link, and title, etc.
[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149930/change-breadcrumbs-home-links-url-2-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149930/change-breadcrumbs-home-links-url-2-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by using translation:
"Home","Sports Store"

Comment: Thanks for answering.

But there is no block that refers to breadcrumbs.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I thought about it the only thing that I have two websites and in one I want it to be "Sports Store" and in another "Tennis Store" but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you use 2 separate themes for 2 websites? If yes, you can translate it from the theme.

In your theme for website 1: <theme dir>/i18n/es_ES.csv:
"Home","Sports Store"


In your theme for website 2: <theme dir>/i18n/es_ES.csv:
"Home","Tennis Store"

Comment: No, I use the same porto theme for two websites.

Maybe it's more of a port issue than anything else...

Comment: So, for me, you should create 2 separate child themes that are based on porto theme, then add translation to these themes as I said above.